# If the value of a given cell is not blank, then cut and paste the whole row into another worksheet

Tags: excel, macros

I am beginner in Excel Macro. I have done a few by just using the Record Macro functions, tweaking them a bit etc.

this time I have to start from scratch and I am lost.

I am looking for a simple way to complete the following:
If the value of a given cell (let's say cell U) is not blank, then cut and paste the whole row into another worksheet AND SAVE the changes.

Can you please help me building up this macro.
I have a very short turnaround for this one and I am having headache already. I am keen on learning but I am missing the basics. I am planning on taking classes soon.

Thanks a bunch for your help guys! Much appreciated :)
Mike

Comment: Hi Mike, i appreciate your Zeal to learn. Sorry that SO cannot create code for you this is what i can suggest. List down the actions you want the macro to achieve and them try small code snippets. Like - 1. Read a Cell value and  Chcek if it is not blank.2. Copy the entire row of cell. 3. Add New sheet.4.....

Comment: you guys are life saver!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As Siva stated, this isn't a do it for me place.  That being said, I happen to have some old code I can copy/paste from easily that is to your benefit.  This works dynamically through all rows with data column U on Sheet 1:

```
Sub CutCopyPaste()
Dim x as Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim i as Integer

x = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
y = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 to x
    If Not Range("U" & i).value = "" Then
        Range("U" & i).EntireRow.Cut Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & y)
        Workbooks("your workbook.xlsm").Save
        y = y + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as solved since it resolves your question.  I'm glad it worked for you.